# Why does "_" (underscore) match "-" (hyphen)?

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I have to look for a PDF manual using this query:

```
root@localhost:test> select * from a where name like '%taz_manual%.pdf%';
+--------------------+------------------+-------------+
| name               | description      |        size | 
+--------------------+------------------+-------------+
| taz-manual-1.1.pdf | Manual v1.0 TA-Z |    31351902 |
| taz-manual-0.2.pdf | Manual v1.0 T1-A |     3578278 |
| taz_manual-2.0.pdf | Manual v2.0 GA-X |   542578278 |
etc........
+--------------------+------------------+-------------+
132 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why am I seeing the the one with dashes when I specify the name to be `taz_manual%.pdf`?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Because the underscore `_` is a wildcard like the percent `%`, except that it only looks for one character.

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use "_" to match any single character and "%" to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).

(From section [3.3.4.7. Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) in the MySQL documentation.)

If you want to use the underscore in `like` as a literal, you have to escape it:

```
select * from a where name like '%taz\_manual%.pdf%';
```

Comment: afaik this is only relevant when you are in a pattern context. e.g. inside a `LIKE` statement. When replacing all `_` with an `-` : `UPDATE sys_file set identifier = REPLACE(identifier, '_', '-') WHERE identifier LIKE '%\_%';`. Notice the escaping inside `LIKE` and no escaping inside `REPLACE`. (I find it strange though that you are not in a pattern context inside replace...)

Comment: @Hafenkranich from the mysql doc: "use the LIKE or NOT LIKE comparison operators"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with space and hyphens while matching strings with exact match:

```
SELECT id FROM location WHERE name = 'IND - HQ';
```

The above query didn't return any records in MySQL. I had to escape the spaces and hyphens and use `LIKE` instead of exact match with equals (=) as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM location WHERE name LIKE 'IND_\-_HQ';
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related? Maybe there was no location row with this exact name...???

Comment: yes, there were rows with location='IND - HQ' and the above did fix the issue faced

Comment: And you know that because you've asked the person who had this question five years before you've posted your answer?