# count values where column doesn't contain underscore

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, sql-like

I have the following query, I would like to modify it so in my count, instead of `movies`, it is values without an underscore. For the second count, I would like values that contain underscores.

Here is the original query:

```
select document
, (count(distinct (case when table_name = 'movies' then keyword else null end)) * 100)
    + (count(distinct (case when table_name = 'movie_summaries' then keyword else null end)) * 50)
    as weight
from indexes where keyword in('the', 'hobbit')
group by document
order by weight desc limit 20
```

The top 3 weights are as follows:

- 300
- 250
- 200

I modified it, so it would look like this, and it didn't seem to work:

```
select document
, (count(distinct (case when table_name not like '%_%' then keyword else null end)) * 100)
    + (count(distinct (case when table_name like '%_%' then keyword else null end)) * 50)
    as weight
from indexes where keyword in('the', 'hobbit')
group by document
order by weight desc limit 20
```

Now the top 3 weights are:

- 100
- 100
- 100

What is causing this to change?

```
CREATE TABLE `indexes` (
    `keyword` CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `document` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `position` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `table_name` CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`keyword`, `document`, `position`, `table_name`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is the underscore is a joker character in sql like. You should escape it like `\_`.

More details: [Why does "_" (underscore) match "-" (hyphen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236818/why-does-underscore-match-hyphen)