# MySQL query LIKE %...% query returning other results?

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to code a PHP script, but we'll just leave it at the SQL part of things since this is where the issue is arising. I've a `SELECT *` query which should only grab from the rows where the user ID matches, and the badge ID meets their userID followed by an underscore. Although, it's grabbing results that shouldn't be included?

Here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user_badges` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1
AND  `badge_id` LIKE  '%1_%'
```

That should only return badges that start/contain `1_`, it is grabbing all the badges that do contain/start with `1_` but it's also grabbing `it215`. If I search a different user ID, for example my own, it will grab all the badges with `3_` AND it's also grabbing `ACH_RoomDecoFurniCount31` which is confusing because it doesn't contain `3_`. Maybe there's more to it? Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "\_" (underscore) match "-" (hyphen)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236818/why-does-underscore-match-hyphen)

Comment: _"So I'm trying to code a PHP script, but we'll just leave it at the SQL part of things since this is where the issue is arising"_ Thankyou! You'd be amazed how many people don't do this.

Comment: This won't work anyway, if you can find the user ID anywhere, because `%1_%` matches `31_abc` as well as `1_abc`. Unless you fully (and unambiguously) delimit the user ID (e.g. make it "at the start only"?), you won't be able to get an unambiguous match. Reconsider your badge ID format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `_` as it's a wildcard character. Your query would should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `user_badges` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1
AND  `badge_id` LIKE  '%1\_%'
```

Comment: Cheers for that! Works amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

_ is also a wildcard in SQL - A substitute for a single character

Answer (score 0):

`_` is also a wildcard character. It means "any single character" (whereas `%` is "any sequence of characters").

You could escape/quote that `_` or use the [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function instead of a pattern match.

```
WHERE badge_id LIKE  '%1\_%'

WHERE locate('1_', badge_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

_ is a wildcard "_ matches exactly one character." so what you are saying is:
% : starts with anything(or nothing)
1: contains 1
_: has exactly 1 of % (or anything, or nothing)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html